# Asymptotic behavior of the number of ways a real plane curve of degree $n$ can intersect a real line

Tags: combinatorics, algebraic-geometry, generating-functions, integer-partitions

Let $C$ and $L$ be plane algebraic curves of degree $n$ and $1$ defined over the real numbers.    For $k=1,\ldots n$, let $h(k)$ be the number of real points where $L$ and $C$ meet with multiplicity $k$ and let $j(k)$ be the number of non-real points where $L$ and $C$ meet with multiplicity $k$.  Thus $j(k)$ is even for all $k$, and $\Sigma h(k)+\Sigma j(k)=n$.

Let $S_n$ be the cardinality of the set of all pairs $(h,j)$ where $h$ and $j$ are functions from the positive integers to the non-negative integers that satisfy these conditions.  Then $S_n$ measures the number of different ways a real plane curve of degree $n$ can intersect a real line, where the definition of ``different'' is implicit in the above.

It's easy to write down a generating function for $S_n$, and then to compute the first several values (beginning with $1,3,4,9,12$) and then to look up this sequence on the OEIS to confirm its accuracy.

After computing a great many more values, it appears that $S_n$ behaves very much like $C\cdot exp(n^\alpha)$ for some constants $C$ and $\alpha$. (In fact, $\alpha$ is in the vicinity of $.64$.)

Is there some simple reason I should have expected this?

Comment: What is the generating function? How is it derived?

Comment: @martycohen:  Just from the definitions of $h$ and $j$, it's clear that the generating function is $1/(s^2t)$ where $s=\prod_ {k \hbox{ even}} 1-x^{k}$ and $t=\prod_{k \hbox{ odd}} 1-x^k$.